# Database and GPGPU

Tags: database, gpgpu

GPGPU as a lot of potentiality on many tasks (not all), especially handling matrices like in a database, at least according all the PR surrounding the subject.

Still I haven't found a database that use GPGPU to speed up performance.

Do you know any open source database that exploit GPGPU? Why GPGPU is so slow to take a hold in markets where it would be such a major improvement?

Comment: data needs to be moved into the gpgpu for processing and then the results moved out.. the process of moving data in and out is too slow and does not work out overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [some research](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/DB/) that has been done in that field. That being said, the limiting factor in many database setups is disk speed. Most databases are so huge they must be stored on disks (unless you are Google or Facebook and can afford terabytes of RAM). This limits the speed at which results can be returned because most of the time is spent seeking on the hard drive, instead of doing computations on the CPU.

Comment: yup, go read about their infrastructure some time, it's fascinating. For an example of the problems they face, Facebook serves up to 600,000 photos PER SECOND. The scale of both of their server farms are just amazing. 

Say a hard drive has a 1/100000 chance of failing each hour. Well, Google literally has that many times that many hard drives, that means they have hardware failures all day long. To combat every byte of data is stored on three hard drives with different power strips, different ethernet connections, etc. They once had a 3 alarm fire in a datacenter and lost no data.

Comment: I've been trying to find modern numbers for Google's data center but I can't find some of the awesome articles I know I've read. Back in 2007, Google was processing 20,000 Terabytes of data every day, I'm sure that's way more than doubled by now. In 2008 they used 4000 computers and 48000 hard drives to sort 1PB of data just for fun (on every run a hard drive broke). If they can pull those kinds of experiments off just on the side, imagine how huge their main infrastructure is.

Comment: http://linuxsysadminblog.com/2010/09/a-day-in-the-life-of-facebook-operations/ Facebook uses 300 TB of RAM just for memcache. I would assume Google is around 1 PB of RAM by now.